# How can I add a new value to a StringValues array, with the same key, thereby modifying my Uri?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

In my application I have a form the user can submit. When they submit the form, the URL looks something like this:

https://localhost:5003/searchresults/q=ford&q=bronco&exclude=color:red&exclude=interior:cloth

On `SearchResults.razor` in `OnInitializedAsync` I have this bit of code:

```
String url = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(navigationManager.Uri);
Uri uri = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(url);
Dictionary<string, StringValues> choices = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
```

In the debugger, I see this for the "choices":

```
{[q, {ford,bronco}]}
{[exclude, {color:red,interior:cloth}]}
```

Say on the next page I want to add:

```
&include=option:siriusxm
&include=option:mudguards
&include=color:blue
```

To make the "choices" look like so:

```
{[q, {ford,bronco}]}
{[exclude, {color:red,interior:cloth}]}
{[include, {option:siriusxm,option:mudguards,color:blue}]}
```

If I were to do this:

```
StringValues sv = new StringValues("option:siriusxm");
choices.Add("include", sv);
```

This will work. However, if I continue, and do this:

```
StringValues sv = new StringValues("option:mudguards");
choices.Add("include", sv);
```

I will get the error:

```
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: include
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
MyAwesomeApplication.Pages.SearchResults.OnInitializedAsync() in SearchResults.razor
+
    choices.Add("include", sv);
```

I'm fairly new at C#, ASP.NET, and Blazor, so I'm not sure how to add **just** a new value to an existing `StringValues` array with the same key.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered other Url builder/parser libraries, such as Flurl?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have not. I'll take a look at Flurl to evaluate it.

Comment: https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-url/#parsing for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary already has an item with the key `include`, you have to append the new value to the existing `StringValues`:

```
StringValues sv = new StringValues("option:siriusxm");
sv = StringValues.Concat(sv,"option:mudguards");
```

or

```
StringValues sv = new StringValues("option:siriusxm");
choices.Add("include", sv);
choices["include"] = StringValues.Concat(choices["include"],"option:mudguards");
```

or even better:

```
StringValues sv = new StringValues(new string[]{"option:siriusxm","option:mudguards"});
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! Thank you.